Nest can't resolve dependencies of the QuizService (?)
Well, I barely ask in online. But I ran out of the option, searched everything available in the internet but couldn't solved this.
I am getting
> Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the QuizService (?). Please make sure that the argument "QuizEntityRepository" at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.
>Potential solutions:
>- Is AppModule a valid NestJS module?
>- If "QuizEntityRepository" is a provider, is it part of the current AppModule?
>- If "QuizEntityRepository" is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AppModule?

import { Repository } from "typeorm";
import { CreateQuizDto } from "./dto/createQuiz.dto";
import { QuizEntity } from "./quiz.entity";
import { InjectRepository } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";

@Injectable()
export class QuizService{
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(QuizEntity) private quizEntityRepository: Repository<QuizEntity>,
      ) {}

    async createNewQuiz (quiz: CreateQuizDto) {
        return await this.quizEntityRepository.save(quiz);
    }
    
}

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { QuizController } from './quiz.controller';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { QuizService } from './quiz.service';
import { QuizEntity } from './quiz.entity';

@Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([QuizEntity])],
    controllers: [QuizController],
    providers: [QuizService],
    exports: [QuizService],
})
export class QuizModule {}

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { QuizModule } from './modules/quiz/quiz.module';
import { QuizService } from './modules/quiz/quiz.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { typeOrmConfig } from './config/typeorm.config';

@Module({
  imports: [QuizModule, TypeOrmModule.forRoot(typeOrmConfig)],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService, QuizService],
})
export class AppModule {}

"dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^10.0.2",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.1",
    "pg": "^8.11.5",
    "postgres": "^3.4.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^10.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.3.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.42.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },

Can anyone tell me why this issue is coming ?
I'm encountering a dependency injection error in my NestJS application. Here's the error message:
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the QuizService (?). Please make sure that the argument "QuizEntityRepository" at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.
Potential solutions:
Is AppModule a valid NestJS module?
If "QuizEntityRepository" is a provider, is it part of the current AppModule?
If "QuizEntityRepository" is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AppModule?
I've reviewed the code and dependencies, but I'm still stuck. Here's the relevant code (replace placeholders with your actual implementation

first of all, have you read the FAQ page?

@micaelLevi Hey thanks for your reply.. The FAQ page didn't helped much.. I have put the QuizService again in AppModule that was causing the issue.. Thanks

If you understand well about nestjs providers and how to read that error, you'll see that the error is because you have registered the QuizService at AppModule. And in this module, you didn't registered all the dependencies of QuizService provider. In your case, adding TypeOrmModule.forFeature([QuizEntity]) to the imports array of AppModule should fix that. But I don't think that this is what you need.
Instead, just drop the QuizService from AppModule, as it has been registered and exposed by the QuizModule, which has been imported by AppModule
